# Persisting data on the page on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to keep the data of the target ordered list before page refresh and then prepend it using jquery on document ready.
Here is my code

```js
// if an refresh event is fired
window.onbeforeunload = function(event){
  //store the messages into sessionStorage
  sessionStorage.setItem('ol', jQuery('#messages'));
  return undefined;
};
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('ol')) {
  // Restore the contents of the ol (message contents)
    var ol = sessionStorage.getItem('ol');
    jQuery('#messages').html(ol);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="chat__main">

    <ol id="messages" class="chat__messages"></ol>

    <div class="chat__footer">
      <form id="message-form" action="">
        <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message" autofocus autocomplete="off"/>
        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
      <button id="send-location"> Send location</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But the code is not working as expected after refreshing the result is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1fzg.png)

Although before refreshing it was 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzRes.png)

Comment: i would suggest taking a look at [JS Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) as it really helps you manage your cookies a lot better. It will make persisting data without server-side code a lot easier.

Comment: Can't pass a jQuery object as value for storage. Can only store strings in storage.

Comment: @Schalk.Netgen suggest you read up on how storage works. Cookies are not a good choice for doing something like this

Comment: I do want to save the content of the targeted jQuery('#messages')

Comment: get the html from that element then `sessionStorage.setItem('ol', jQuery('#messages').html());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @charlietfl     Here is what works for me

```js
// if an refresh event is fired
window.onbeforeunload = function(event){
  //store the messages into sessionStorage
  sessionStorage.setItem('ol', jQuery('#messages').html());
  return undefined;
};
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('ol')) {
  // Restore the contents of the ol (message contents)
    var ol = sessionStorage.getItem('ol');
    jQuery('#messages').html(ol);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `localStorage` As data stored in `localStorage` persists until explicitly deleted. Changes made are saved and available for all current and future visits to the site.

For `sessionStorage`, changes are only available per window (or tab in browsers like Chrome and Firefox). Changes made are saved and available for the current page, as well as future visits to the site on the same window. Once the window is closed, the storage is deleted.

More details on this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage